# Running FastAPI on Google Cloud Run (Docker Image)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I'm looking to build a Docker image to run [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) on Google Cloud Run. FastAPI uses Uvicorn as an ASGI server and [Uvicorn recommend using Gunicorn with the Uvicorn worker class](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-with-gunicorn) for production deployments. FastAPI themselves also have some excellent documentation on [using Gunicorn with Uvicorn](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/uk/deployment/server-workers/#gunicorn-with-uvicorn-workers). I even see that FastAPI provide an official image combining the two (
[uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker)) but this comes with a [warning](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#-warning-you-probably-dont-need-this-docker-image):

> You are probably using Kubernetes or similar tools. In that case, you
> probably don't need this image (or any other similar base image). You
> are probably better off building a Docker image from scratch

This warning basically explains that replication would be handled at *cluster-level* and doesn't need to be handled at *process-level*. This makes sense. I am however not quite sure if Cloud Run falls into this category? Essentially it is an abstracted and managed Knative service which therefore runs on Kubernetes.

My question is, should I be installing Gunicorn along with Uvicorn in my Dockerfile and handling replication at process-level? Along the lines of:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "app.main:app", "-w", "4", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80"]
```

Or should I stick with Uvicorn, a single process, and let Cloud Run (Kubernetes) handle replication at cluster-level? E.g.

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A. Let's go the big scale first.**

At the time of writing Cloud Run instances can be set to a maximum of 1000 [concurrency requests](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency). And CPUs can be set to 4 vCPUs.

Going back to basics a bit. Cloud Run will span many instances, each will work individually, and each could handle the maximum allowed concurrency, so each could handle 1000 requests. If you set multiple CPUs you need to handle multi processes.

When we talk about so large number we need to be cautious. If your container is big enough in CPU/Memory terms to handle this traffic, you may want to use a process manager (gunicorn) to start several Uvicorn threads (workers), as your referenced images do. So you can use the docker container.

**B. Being on small scale.**

On the other hand if you set 1 vCPU and be single threaded, you don't need gunicorn for process manager. You still can have concurrency enabled but not on the top level, maybe at the lower level, that fits your 1 vCPU model, something like 80 requests for concurrency. In this situation you will have on large traffic, many instances started by Cloud Run, and you rely at Cloud Run to spawn as many instances as needed, which does really nice. It's like a Kubernetes on top of your simple container.

I would suggest start with single process, build a container that doesn't use the referenced container, and only swap B to version A, when you know there are benefits(costs wise) to have larger instances.

Comment: Thanks for the scale breakdown. Just so I'm clear, on the small scale you recommend starting with my second code snippet: Uvicorn with a single process (no Uvicorn workers and no Gunicorn) in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, sure, try that out.